# Weka Expected-Maximum clustering result explanation

Tags: bigdata, cluster-analysis, weka

I currently have a very large `dataset` with 2 attributes which contain only strings. The first attribute has search queries (single words) and the second attribute has their corresponding categories.

So the data is set up like this (a search query can have multiple categories):

Search Query | Category

X | Y

X | Z

A | B

C | G

C | H

Now I'm trying to use clustering algorithms to get an idea of the different groups my data is comprised of. I read somewhere that when using a clustering algorithm with just strings it is recommended to first use the Expected Maximum clustering algorithm to get a sense of how many clusters I need and then use that with K-means.

Unfortunately, I'm still very new to machine learning and Weka, so I'm constantly reading up on everything to teach myself. I might be making some very simple mistakes here so bear with me, please :)

So I imported a sample (100.000 lines out of 2.7 million) of my `dataset` in Weka and used the EM clustering algorithm and it gives me the following results:

```
=== Run information ===

Scheme:       weka.clusterers.EM -I 100 -N -1 -X 10 -max -1 -ll-cv 1.0E-6 -ll-iter 1.0E-6 -M 1.0E-6 -K 10 -num-slots 1 -S 100
Relation:     testrunawk1_weka_sample.txt
Instances:    100000
Attributes:   2
              att1
              att2
Test mode:    split 66% train, remainder test


=== Clustering model (full training set) ===


EM
==

Number of clusters selected by cross-validation: 2
Number of iterations performed: 14

[135.000 lines long table with strings, 2 clusters and their values]

Time is taken to build a model (percentage split): 28.42 seconds

Clustered Instances

0      34000 (100%)


Log-likelihood: -20.2942
```

So should I infer from this that I should be using 2 or 34000 clusters with k-means?

Unfortunately, both seem unusable for me. What I was hoping for is that I get for example 20 clusters which I can then look at individually to figure out what kind of groups can be found in my data. 2 clusters seems like too low with the wide amount of categories etc in my data and 34000 clusters would be way too much to inspect manually.

I am unsure if I'm doing something wrong in either the Weka EM algorithm settings (set to standard now) or if my data is just a mess, and if so how would I go about making this work?

I am still very much learning how this all works, so any advice is much appreciated! If there is a need for more examples of my settings or anything else just tell me and I'll get it for you. I could also send you this `dataset` if that is easier, but it's too large to paste in here. :)

Comment: This is not a feasible clustering problem. Re*think* your problem, define what a good answer is first.

Comment: EM etc. cannot find similar strings. They will just go by string equality. But I don't think any clustering will help you.

Comment: Oh wow I was sure this could be done with clustering. What I want to find out is what kind of people use this search engine. My plan was to use the clustering to get several clusters that I can then look at to figure out which subjects can be found in each cluster. That would then tell me about those people's interests I figured. Could you point me in a direction on how I would go about figuring out who the users are based on search logs? :) What I was hoping to get is for example:  cluster 1 is made up of healthcare & biology subjects, cluster 2 is made up of IT subjects, etc.

Comment: Would it be possible with clustering If I were to add more features such as string length and the time at which the search query was executed? Then it wouldn't just be strings in the dataset.

Comment: You are thinking in hacks to make the algorithm 'run', not in what problem to solve. Are 'string length' and 'time' helpful to identify similar people? I don't think they help answering the right question.

Comment: Clustering short strings tends to not work any better than just finding the most frequent strings. It's just too little information content, too much ambiguity.

Comment: That's a very good point, thank you. I could just take a look at which categories of search queries show up more often and that would give me some sense of the user interest. But that is still sort of a guessing game. Because a query can have multiple categories there is a natural overlap between different queries, so I was hoping that clustering would be able to find those overlaps resulting in clusters that describe a more general category compared to one single very specific category.

Comment: For example, there are categories for all sorts of birds. One category of those birds might show up a lot, but all those other bird categories that show up should be included there as well. 

Aside from looking at which specific categories show up a lot, is it possible (maybe with another method than clustering) to get a better sense of this data?

Comment: A clustering cannot learn what a bird is. That is a supervised concept, and full of exceptions. There are birds that can't fly, etc. - so don't expect it to make a cluster "searches for birds".